# obfuscate: Make file-min.js?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

For example, when I download Jquery, I see there is always 2 file: jquery.js and jquery-min.js.

How could they create jQuery-min.js -> in this file, it is not only compressed but also obfuscated. Which tool is best to do this?

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, would it be also possible as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ pretty cool... and I believe jQuery is compressed using that. There are .NET, PHP and other versions [HERE](http://dean.edwards.name/download/#packer).

For Visual Studio I use this: http://yuicustomtool.codeplex.com/.

Checkout this too for CSS: https://csscompressor.net/

**UPDATE:** Recently I came across [THIS](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/). Its an Online YUI Compressor. Its useful if you are not able to run YUI Compressor EXE, or you haven't wrote your JS to be minification friendly (it adds `;` by itself to the end of the object's definition for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just have checked it out with .NET packer but after getting the script obfuscated. It does not work with my application...

Comment: .NET version I guess is little buggy, you can try the web version, and you must follow the rules for writing JavaScript in order for it to work. For example, because all the code is minified to be in one line, you must end each function with `;` and also use `;` at end of each line (so browser can tell where the statement ends). Try to have your code look like this: http://javascriptcompressor.com/content/CompressedExample.aspx

Comment: @gnarf: I said "I believe". ;)